# How Can I Capture Output From Programs That Use curses?

Tags: curses, pv

For example, the `pv` utility shows me the current rate of data transfer and updates every second. I'd like to save that output to a file, so that I can see at what rate data was being transferred second by second. I can't use a simple redirect like `(pv /dev/zero > /dev/null) 2> out.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen), which provides a kind of virtual text terminal.  When you run a program like pv from within screen (by typing `screen pv`), you can save a snapshot of the screen with [Control-a, h](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_17.html).